GraphDB JDBC - from python?
I'm trying to setup a way to execute SQL queries on GraphDB pre-configured JDBC tables. I got it to work using a SQL engine like SQuirrel SQL Client, but so far I have not been successful in Python. I tried using the python package jaydebeapi, but I'm getting an error that my class GraphDB localhost is not found.
Does anybody have experience with using this python package - especially in combination with Ontotext GraphDB, or alternatives, and can give some tips in the right direction?
import jaydebeapi

# JDBC connection details
jdbc_url = "jdbc:graphdb:url=http://localhost:7200"
driver_class = "com.ontotext.graphdb.jdbc.remote.Driver"
driver_jar = "C:/Users/franken/Desktop/squirrelSQL/plugins/graphdb-jdbc-remote-10.0.0.jar"  # Replace with the path to your GraphDB JDBC driver jar file
alias_name = "GraphDB localhost"

# SQL query to execute
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM GRAPHDB.IMAGINGBACKUPS.SOFTWARE" 

# Establish connection
with jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=alias_name, url=jdbc_url, driver_args=None, jars=driver_jar, libs=None) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(sql_query)
        curs.fetchall()

Error I receive:
(jdbc-py3.12) PS C:\Users\franken\jdbc\jdbc> python usesql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\jdbc\usesql.py", line 13, in <module>
    with jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=alias_name, url=jdbc_url, driver_args=None, jars=driver_jar, libs=None) as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 221, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    jpype.JClass(jclassname)
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py", line 99, in __new__
    return _jpype._getClass(jc)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Class GraphDB localhost is not found

Note, I get a similar, but not exactly the same error 'java.lang.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory' error when I change the jclassname to driver_class.
(jdbc-py3.12) PS C:\Users\franken\jdbc\jdbc> python usesql.py
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassLoader.java", line 521, in java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
java.lang.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\jdbc\usesql.py", line 13, in <module>
    with jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=driver_class, url=jdbc_url, driver_args=None, jars=driver_jar, libs=None) as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\franken\jdbc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jaydebeapi\__init__.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
java.lang.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

